# Read xml from azure blob storage and retrive datasets from it using powershell

Tags: azure-blob-storage, powershell-4.0

I have an xml file in azure blob and I can access it using url. I'm able to read xml using powershell.

```
$DOC= New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument;
$DOC.Load("https://logs.blob.core.windows.net/../../xxx.xml");
$DOC.Root.Dataset;
```

which gives me all attributes.

But I need to get each dataset as a whole, from xml.

I have tried using 
    $DOC.SelectSingleNode("//Dataset");
    $DOC.SelectNodes("Root/Dataset");
I couldn't get it.

Saving file to local and reading the file using Import-Clixml ".\xxx.xml" is not my requirement.
Different xmls may have different child nodes, I need to get datasets from whatever the xml I give.

Comment: Could you provide two sample documents? Currently it is hard to understand why $DOC.Root.Dataset is not what you want and what you mean with 'get each dataset as a whole'. Please try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to get all the tag names of each child nodes.

If so, please try the following PowerShell script:

```
$DOC= New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument;
$DOC.Load("http://garyteststorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/text.xml");
$xml = $DOC.FirstChild
printDataset($xml)
function printDataset($nodes){
    foreach($dataset in $nodes.ChildNodes){
        $dataset.LocalName
        if($dataset.ChildNodes.LocalName -ne '#text'){
            printDataset($dataset)
        }
    }
}
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Any `JSON` approach ?